# Angular RxJS Copy Value from One Element to Next in Observable Array

Tags: angular, rxjs

A newB to declarative patterns and RxJS...

My goal is to transform an observable and copy a value from one element to the next in the array.

With help from Deborah Kurata, this example sets the "qtyToComplete" correctly using the Scan operator.  This is an example of what needs to be copied from one array element to the next.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-scan-deborahk-wym5cc?file=index.ts

This next bit is closer to my real-world application and I'm stuck.
There are 3 steps to build a quantity of 150 rakes.
In each step the "qtyToComplete" (Qty Required) needs to match the Qty Completed from
the prior element.

**Enter Step**:  1

**Enter Current Quantity Completed for Step**: 10

The Qty Completed changes to 40.  The 40 needs to be copied to the Qty Required in Step 2 (and so on).

The second grid incorporates the scan operator which does not work in this case.  I'm not sure how to combine/merge the results from the scan with the original data to return the new observable.  Also, the observable returned to the first grid is an Array but when the scan is added to the observable for the second grid an "object" is returned which causes an error.
Am not tied to using scan.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zewhzq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! In the second Stackblitz, I'm not following how this works. After finishing a step and moving to the next, it doesn't seem to retain those values? So if I enter something for step 1, it changes the values temporarily, but then if I change to step 2, the step 1 values are gone? I'm not sure I can help until I get a better handle on what this is trying to achieve. Can you provide a bit more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scan works better with merge than with combineLatest. Making that change it *seemed* to work. But I'm still a bit unclear about the requirements, so I'm not certain of the details.

The updated Stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assembly-scan

The basic code is:

```
  stepsCombinedScan$ = merge(this.steps$, this.selectedDataAction$).pipe(
    scan(
      (acc, value) =>
        value instanceof Array ? [...value] : this.modifySteps(acc, value),
      [] as Step[]
    )
  );
```

Notice the change from `combineLatest` to `merge` to combine the steps and the action.

If you look at the Stackblitz, I also changed the entry of the two inputs into one action, since it didn't seem to make sense to process them as separate actions. That is, you would only want the data to change when *both* were changed not when one or the other is changed. (See the Stackblitz for a note about this.)

And ... of course ... I needed to remove my kind closing because ... you know ... bots.

Comment: Thank you! What a great example!  The reason for two separate actions with combineLatest is that the change of "Step" needs to highlight that step in the grid.  The quantities would not be impacted by the step change.

Comment: Did you see in the code how it now handles the step change highlight?

Comment: @DeborahK, I heard that `combineLastest` is retired in the latest rxjs. What is the replacement? Is it the `merge` operator? Thanks.

Comment: There is some confusion about that. There were originally two ways to use `combineLatest`: (1) as a pipeable operator: `pipe(combineLatest(...)` and (2) as a creation function: `x$ = combineLatest(...). The pipeable version (1) is being deprecated and replaced with `combineLatestWith`. That way we don't have the same named function being used two different ways.